# Validate email format in firestore security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to make sure that if the user is updating its email, it should be a correct email address (at least including a "@" and finishing by a ".xxx")

I understood I have to use [matches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches). I tried:

```
request.resource.data.email.matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)
```

But it seems it isn't RE2 compliant:

```
i  firestore: Change detected, updating rules...
⚠  firestore.rules:30:63 - ERROR Unexpected '_'.
⚠  firestore.rules:30:63 - ERROR Unexpected '_'.
⚠  firestore.rules:30:63 - ERROR mismatched input '_' expecting {'&&', '.', '==', '>', '>=', '[', '<', '<=', '-', '%', '!=', '||', '+', '}', ';', '/', '*', '?', 'in', 'is'}
⚠  firestore.rules:30:81 - ERROR token recognition error at: '\'
⚠  firestore.rules:30:82 - ERROR token recognition error at: '\'
⚠  firestore.rules:30:94 - ERROR Unexpected '$'.
⚠  firestore.rules:30:95 - ERROR Missing 'match' keyword before path.
⚠  firestore.rules:30:97 - ERROR mismatched input ')' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
⚠  firestore.rules:48:3 - ERROR Unexpected '}'.
✔  firestore: Rules updated.
```

Is there a correct email RE2 regex somewhere? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches), matches() takes a string parameter.  This means you should put your regular expression inside double quotes to tell the language that you have a string value.

Comment: Ok indeed, thank you! Now my regex doesn't seem to work. Any idea where I can find a valid one ?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.  Though, I will point out that asking for references to offsite material is off topic for Stack Overflow.